# Prevent inner table from Filtering in Nested Html table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two nested tables. One outer table and inside every row of outer table I have inner table. My problem is when I am filtering using `searchBox` it filters both the tables outer and inner. I don't want to filter my inner table rows. Look at my problem I don't want my inner table to be filtered.

```js
var $rows = $('#top_table tr');

$('#txtsearch').keyup(function () {
 var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

 $rows.show().filter(function () {
  var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
  return !~text.indexOf(val);
 }).hide();

});
```

```css
tr.top_tr td {
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 min-width: 16%;
}

th {
 font: bold 11px"Helvetica Neue", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #4f6b72;
 border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
 border-top: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
 background: #CAE8EA url(images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat;
 width: 16%;
}

td {
 border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
 background: #fff;
 padding: 0px;
 color: #4f6b72;
 width: 14%;
}

td:first-child {
 border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
}

table {
 padding: 0px;
}

#top_table {
 padding: 10px;
 width: 800px;
}

body {
 padding: 10px;
}

.subtable {
 width: 100%;
}

.body-td {
 border: none;
 width: 16%;
}

.collapse {
 position: relative;
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease;
 -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease;
 -o-transition: height 0.35s ease;
 transition: height 0.35s ease;
 display: inline;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
}

tr.collapse>td {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtsearch" />
<table id="top_table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>List Name</th>
         <th>No. Records</th>
         <th>Avail. Records</th>
         <th>Creation Date</th>
         <th>Last Used</th>
         <th>Performance</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="6">
            <table class="subtable">
               <tbody>
                  <tr class="top_tr accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#top_table" href="#collapseOne">
                     <td>LIST NO. 1</td>
                     <td>30000</td>
                     <td>3340</td>
                     <td>05-26-2004</td>
                     <td>21 days ago</td>
                     <td>7.3 % TRANSFER RATE</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr >
                     <td colspan="6">
                        <table>
                           <tbody id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="body-td" colspan="6">THIS IS A BIG ROW IN A TABLE</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="body-td" colspan="6">THIS IS A BIG ROW IN A TABLE</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="body-td" colspan="6">THIS IS A BIG ROW IN A TABLE</td>
                              </tr>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="6">
            <table class="subtable">
               <tbody>
                  <tr class="top_tr  accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#top_table" href="#collapseTwo">
                     <td>LIST NO. 2</td>
                     <td>30000</td>
                     <td>3340</td>
                     <td>05-26-2004</td>
                     <td>21 days ago</td>
                     <td>7.3 % TRANSFER RATE</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr >
                     <td colspan="6">
                        <table>
                           <tbody id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="body-td" colspan="6">THIS IS A BIG ROW IN A TABLE</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="body-td" colspan="6">THIS IS A BIG ROW IN A TABLE</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="body-td" colspan="6">THIS IS A BIG ROW IN A TABLE</td>
                              </tr>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="6">
            <table class="subtable">
               <tbody>
                  <tr class="top_tr">
                     <td>LIST NO. 3</td>
                     <td>30000</td>
                     <td>3340</td>
                     <td>05-26-2004</td>
                     <td>21 days ago</td>
                     <td>7.3 % TRANSFER RATE</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="6">THIS IS A BIG ROW IN A TABLE</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: All `top_table` rows having `subtable` alone. you have to provide the correct table structure

Comment: What do you mean by `I don't want to filter my inner table rows`? You have one outer table and many inner tables. It doesn't make any sense, just think about it. I think what you want is to filter inner table and exclude outer table from filtering. Or if you intended to filter outer table cols and exclude inner table please clarify your question.

Comment: Filter Outer table by excluding the inner table rows @MasoudKeshavarz

Comment: Any one with any idea??

Comment: @Ricky what do you want to filter in outer table? Cols?

Comment: Rows@MasoudKeshavarz

Comment: Could you please provide an example? Talk about a specific value in search box like `LIST` or `LIST NO. 1` and describe what do you expect to be shown as a result.

Comment: The problem is that when i search for anything in the searchbox .It will filter both the outer and inner tables and show results .Also the inner tables ,If do not contain anything related to the search does not open.Which means the filteration applied to them also and i don't want this inner table to undergo filteration@MasoudKeshavarz

Comment: Any have the answer ???

Comment: Got answer to this problem in another way please check below this will help you also ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Everyone i got an answer which is very much shocking i just focused on what i actually want and that was just to ignore even rows of table that contains inner tables.
And the answer to this is :var rows= $("tr:odd") and then i applied filteration on these rows .:) Thanks for you precious time.